# Вставка массива данных из Бд

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery

Помогите сделать так, чтобы в окне с чекбоксами создавались новые поля с чекбоксами и именами взятыми из PHP-файла.

```html
<div class="ui cards cdsniga">
  <div class="card card-employees">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="header">Employees Access</div>
      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Filter by Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by Name">
        </div>

        <div class="field">
          <label>Filter by Company</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Filter by Company">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="description">
        <h4 class="ui dividing header">Employees</h3>
          <div class="ui very relaxed horizontal list">
            <div class="item">
              <div class="content mmmddd">
                <div class="ui checkbox checkk">
                  <input type="checkbox">
                  <label>john doe</label>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP-код:

```
    <?php   
$db = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1","localand","1234")
or die('Could not connext to mysql server');
mysql_select_db("survey",$db) 
or die('Could not select db');
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM employees order by id",$db);
 while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
 $name = $row[0];
 }
mysql_close($db);

 ?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделать при вводе в поля фильтров асинхронный запрос к серверу, получить список сотрудников, удовлетворяющим фильтру, или сразу форму под Employes, показать ее.

Экспериментируйте с JS и примерами jQuery.post() + небольшой php скрипт на сервере. Есть уже готовые решение вроде http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/ (довольно тяжелый, нужен UI). Вот тут еще можно почитать: https://habrahabr.ru/post/74713/

Или сразу выдать на страницу массив объектов сотрудников с как минимум тремя полями: `[{id:id, name:name, company:company},...]`. Такую структуру данных можно легко и быстро получить с помощью php функции json_encode() из обычного массива php, который можно вынуть из БД. Ну а фильтрацию сделать через JavaScript по событию change полей фильтров (на форме у вас их два)

Каким вариантом пойти - зависит от количества данных. Если у вас десятки сотрудников, то проще сразу выдать их на страницу и не гонять туда-сюда запросы. Если у вас их десятки тысяч, то лучше через AJAX получать порции не более N штук, подходящих по фильтру.

Comment: в любом случае лучше через ajax

Answer (score 0):

Делал аналогичное с `<Select>`. Аяксом отправить данные в php файл, получить ответ в виде JSON, создавать чекбоксы пока не кончится массив и каждое значение массива присваивать к новому чекбоксу.
Не уверен, что это правильно, но у меня с `<Select>` работает.
Пример

```
 form.id = "select_table_del";
                form.name = "select_table_del";
                select.id = "tables";
                select.name = "tables";
                parent.appendChild(form);
                hidden.id = "table_del";
                hidden.name = "table_del";
                hidden.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                hidden.value = $("#delete").val();
                form.appendChild(hidden);
                form.appendChild(select);
                for(i = 0; i<result.length; i++){
                    option.id = "option" + i;
                    option.name = "option" + i;
                    switch(table){
                        case "image":
                            option.text = result[i].primary_name;
                            break;
                        case "model":
                            option.text = result[i].title;
                            break;
                        case "news":
                            option.text = result[i].title;
                            break;
                        case "users":
                            option.text = result[i].login;
                            break;
                        case "category":
                            option.text = result[i].name;
                            break;
                    }

                    select.appendChild(option.cloneNode(true));
                }
```

Comment: Можете прислать пример?

Comment: Скину через часа 3-4

Comment: Добавил пример как я делал